# Cannot run tf.math.reduce_std and tf.math.reduce_variance in Tensorflow? (Error: Input must be either real or complex)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a problem about calculating the standard deviation and variance of a tensor which fills with random variables. It throws a message which is related with input error.

Here is my code snippet which is shown below.

```
# Create a tensor with 50 random values between 0 and 100
E = tf.constant(np.random.randint(low=0, high=100, size=50))
print(E)

# Calculate the standard deviation and variance
print(tf.math.reduce_std(E))
print(tf.math.reduce_variance(E))
```

Here is the error message which is shown on the console.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Noyan\PycharmProjects\1_Fundementals_of_Tensorflow\001_introduction_to_tensors.py", line 515, in <module>
    print(tf.math.reduce_std(E))
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\1_Fundementals_of_Tensorflow\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py", line 206, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\1_Fundementals_of_Tensorflow\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py", line 2558, in reduce_std
    variance = reduce_variance(input_tensor, axis=axis, keepdims=keepdims)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\1_Fundementals_of_Tensorflow\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py", line 206, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\1_Fundementals_of_Tensorflow\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py", line 2499, in reduce_variance
    raise TypeError("Input must be either real or complex")
TypeError: Input must be either real or complex
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For `tf.math.reduce_std` and `tf.math.reduce_variance` input tensor must be in real or complex type. So, just convert your data to float before passing to these functions like this:

```
E = tf.constant(np.random.randint(low=0, high=100, size=50))
print(E)

# Add this line
E = tf.cast(E, dtype=tf.float32) # Convert to float 32

print(tf.math.reduce_std(E))
print(tf.math.reduce_variance(E))
```

Answer (score 2):

To find the variance of our tensor, we need access to `tensorflow_probability`

```py
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

tfp.stats.variance(E)
```

And If you use the below code, convert your data to float before passing to these functions like this

```py
tf.math.reduce_variance(tf.cast(E, dtype=tf.float32))
```

To find the Standard deviation, convert your data to float before passing to these functions.

```py
tfp.stats.stddev(tf.cast(E, dtype=tf.float32))

tf.math.reduce_std(tf.cast(E, dtype=tf.float32))
```